# When calling scripts from Python files to c# code, the IronPython library does not see libraries from Python code

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

Using a Python script that uses `pyvisa` to access third-party devices. How can I call this script in my C# program so that there is no error `No module named 'pyvisa'`? The python code itself works and sees all the imports.

```
    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    var scope = engine.CreateScope();
    var script = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("script.py");
    script.Execute(scope);
    var result = scope.GetVariable<int>("result");
    Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
```